# Why a pointer to a 16-bit register is uword?

Tags: c, pointers, microcontroller

Have lots of 16-bit registers in a processor that are defined like

```
#define CAN_REG01              (*((uword volatile far *) 0x200000))
```

Why do we need (uword*) pointer if a register and its value is still 16-bit?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This define simple allows you to write things like `CAN_REG01 = ...` or indeed the other way around, `uword regvalue = CAN_REG01`. What do you not understand?

Comment: Are you wondering why you have to cast it to a pointer? Or what `uword` is (and we wonder that too, since it's not a standard type)? Can you please elaborate a little on your problem?

Comment: `0x200000` is of type `unsigned int`, you can't dereference it without a cast to a pointer.

Comment: @mch Not even `unsigned int`, just `int`.

Comment: I am sorry, right, uword is not standart. uword means double word = 32 bit. But my register is 16-bit. That what I am not understand.

Comment: if you want to read a uword, obviously you must declard the address as pointer th uword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into your data sheet you will recognize that the address of the CAN_REG01 is `0x200000`.

To provide you with something readable that you can use to write to (and read from) this special function register (SFR) someone created that define that let you use the name `CAN_REG01` like some ordinary variable.

You have to tell the compiler that you want to write at the address `0x200000` so you have to treat it as a pointer. Additionally you have to tell the compiler about the size of the data that is behind this pointer. Obviously the CAN_REG01 register has the size of an `uword` (whatever that does that mean on your specific platform). The `volatile` have to be added to force the compiler not to optimize out access to this address because some processor internals or Interrupts may change it independently from your code. Also otherwise the compiler may remove consecutive assignments to this register, because he thinks that only the last one does matter..

Defining SFRs  this way is very common on embedded platform bare metal compilers.

Comment: Thank you. My description was not clear. uword means 32-bit, but the register is 16-bit. That's what I wonder: why not  (*((word volatile far *) 0x200000)), where word == 16-bit?

Comment: if `word` is 16 bit i bet `uword` also is 16bit. The only difference is the signedness